# Assigning a function call to a variable in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Does assigning a variable to a function call actually call the function then or just store it (so it's ready to be called)?

For example does:

```
val userData = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {
        override fun onCompleted(`object`: JSONObject?, response: GraphResponse?) {
            Log.d(TAG, `object`.toString())
        }

    }
)
```

actually call `GraphRequest.newMeRequest()`?

Comment: It calls the function then - quite easy to try too...

Comment: Another example around how to call a function - https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/functions. So, it calls function and saves result to userData.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that code first calls `GraphRequest.newMeRequest()`, and assigns its result to `userData`.

In general, any time you see parens after a function name (or lambda), that will call the function.

If you want a reference to the function *without* calling it (e.g. to call later, or to return or pass to another function), you can use `GraphRequest::newMeRequest`.  You'll then need to pass the relevant arguments when you call it.

More info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will call the `GraphRequest.newMeRequest(..)` method and assign the result to `userData` immediately. If you want the field to be initialized at a later time, but only when the field is first accessed, use a [lazy delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy).

```
val userData by lazy { /* call method */ }
```